# How to delete all but the latest revision of Google cloud run container images?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, revision-control, google-cloud-run

I am hosting my containerized application using Google cloud run. To save cost, I want to delete all but the active revisions of my application's Docker image.

I use a job of my GitLab pipeline to handle the credentials and settings using environment variables.

I can list my revisions like so:

```bash
gcloud run revisions list --region="$GCP_REGION"
```

Answer (score 6):

The latest revision of your application is the only one active. Exploiting that fact, we can delete all other revisions:

```bash
gcloud run revisions list --filter="status.conditions.type:Active AND status.conditions.status:'False'" --format='value(metadata.name)' | xargs -r -L1 gcloud run revisions delete --quiet
```

Sources:

- https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html
- https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/run

Comment: the xargs command needs `-L1` flag so that it also works when you have several obsolete versions. Here's the complete line:

`gcloud run revisions list --filter="status.conditions.type:Active AND status.conditions.status:'False'" --format='value(metadata.name)' | xargs -r -L1 gcloud run revisions delete --quiet`

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I updated the command and added the man pages to both `xargs` and `glcoud run` as sources.

Answer (score 2):

Previous response by Bengt is perfect, but as I can't comment just want to add that you need to add --region in my case this is the command:

```
gcloud run revisions list --region=europe-west1 --filter="status.conditions.type:Active AND status.conditions.status:'False'" --format='value(metadata.name)' | xargs -r -L1 gcloud run revisions delete --region=europe-west1 --quiet
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/574652)